# Navigation between two screens Roku Developer - BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to navigate between two screens on button click back and forth. I have below code.

TestScreen1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component name="TestScreen1" extends="Scene"> 
    <children>
      <Label id="myLabelScreen1" 
        width="1280" 
        height="720" 
        horizAlign="center"
        vertAlign="top"
        translation="[0, 30]"
        />
        <Poster
            id="screenAPosterScreen1"
            translation="[470, 300]"
            width="0.0"
            height="0.0"
            visible="true">
        </Poster>
         <Button
            id="screen1Button"
            text="Go to Screen 2"
            width="100"
            height ="70"
            translation="[470, 450]"
            showFocusFootprint="true"
         />
 </children>
<!-- BrightScript Portion -->
<script type="text/brightscript" uri="TestScreen1.brs" />
<script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/source/Main.brs" />
<!-- End of BrightScript Portion -->
</component>
```

TestScreen1.brs

```
function init()
     m.top.setFocus(true)
     m.myLabel = m.top.findNode("myLabelScreen1")
     m.screenAPoster = m.top.findNode("screenAPosterScreen1")
            
     m.Button = m.top.findNode("screen1Button")
     m.Button.observeField("buttonSelected", "onButton1Press")
     m.Button.setFocus(true)
        
     jsonData = ParseJson(m.global.mystuff)
        
     m.myLabel.text = jsonData.screens.a.title
     m.screenAPoster.uri = jsonData.screens.a.logo
        
     'Set the font size
     m.myLabel.font.size = 92
        
     'Set the color to light blue
      m.myLabel.color = "0x72D7EEFF"
end function
```

Now TestScreen2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component name="TestScreen2" extends="Scene"> 
    <children>
      <Label id="myLabelScreen2" 
        width="1280" 
        height="720" 
        horizAlign="center"
        vertAlign="top"
        translation="[0, 30]"
        />
        <Poster
            id="screenAPosterScreen2"
            translation="[470, 300]"
            width="0.0"
            height="0.0"
            visible="true">
        </Poster>
        
         <Button
            id="screen2Button"
            text="Go to Screen 1"
            width="100"
            height ="70"
            translation="[470, 450]"
            showFocusFootprint="true"
         />
 </children>
<!-- BrightScript Portion -->
<script type="text/brightscript" uri="TestScreen2.brs" />
<script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/source/Main.brs" />
<!-- End of BrightScript Portion -->
</component>
```

TestScreen2.brs

```
function init()
      m.top.setFocus(true)
      m.top.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"
      m.myLabel = m.top.findNode("myLabelScreen2")
      m.screenAPoster = m.top.findNode("screenAPosterScreen2")
            
      m.Button = m.top.findNode("screen2Button")
      m.Button.observeField("buttonSelected", "onButton2Press")
      m.Button.setFocus(true)
            
      jsonData = ParseJson(m.global.mystuff)
            
      m.myLabel.text = jsonData.screens.b.title
      m.screenAPoster.uri = jsonData.screens.b.logo
            
      'Set the font size
       m.myLabel.font.size = 92
            
       'Set the color to light blue
       m.myLabel.color = "0x72D7EEFF"
end function
```

Main.brs file

```
sub Main()
    print "in showChannelSGScreen"
    'Indicate this is a Roku SceneGraph application'
    screen = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
    m.port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
    screen.setMessagePort(m.port)

    scene = screen.CreateScene("TestScreen1")

    m.global = screen.getGlobalNode()
    m.global.AddField("mystuff", "string", false)

    port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
    request = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")

    request.AddHeader("secret-key", "$2b$10$uFTmoV/NUudBt3K/t8h9H.c08SIwq29I9RiZskcr5k.tU8lvpwfJ2")
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    request.EnablePeerVerification(false)
    request.EnableHostVerification(false)
    request.RetainBodyOnError(true)
    request.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
    request.InitClientCertificates()
    request.SetMessagePort(port)

    request.SetURL("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e7e4017862c46101abf301f")

    response = ParseJson(request.GetToString())

    m.global.mystuff = request.GetToString()

    screen.show()

    while(true)
        msg = wait(0, m.port)
        msgType = type(msg)
        if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"
            if msg.isScreenClosed() then return
        end if
    end while
end sub

sub onButton1Press(event as object)
    print "go to screen2"
    'how to navigate to screen2
end sub

sub onButton2Press(event as object)
     print "go to screen2"
    'how to navigate to screen1
end sub
```

How do I navigate between two screens back and forth, on click of screen1Button go to Screen 2 and vice versa navigate back between two screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *MultiStack* functionality implemented in [SGDEX](https://github.com/rokudev/SceneGraphDeveloperExtensions) to save state of each screen and swap them.

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one "scene" in a Roku application. Change your test2 xml to extend "group".
Also avoid calling API in the Main, create a separate Task node to do so.
Also for m.Button.observeField("buttonSelected", "onButton2Press"), define the sub in the same brs files because scoping matters.

Better you start with the getting started document, to get the basics right.

Comment: If such document exists can you provide link ?